# How do I implement Dijkstra's on a graph with 2 given edge weights with condition to use the other one?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am stuck in a problem where I cannot figure out how to apply Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest distance between A and C when each edge have 2 weights and the second weight (on the right) can only be used as the edge weight if we visit any of the underlined nodes, else we only use the first weight as the edge weight.

[image]

I tried solving it using normal Dijkstra's but got stuck as it does not move forward to loop back to A and return the shortest path from A to C.

Consider the first weights as the time taken by your SUV to an edge and second weight as the time taken by another car which is a small car to reach a node. You can only change cars on the underlined nodes and once you sit in a small car you can take the second weight as the time taken, but if the second time is bigger than first time you can also use the time one in the small car.

[use this picture for below answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDok9.png)

The shortest path from a to c should be [A,D,E,A,D,C] 270 min

Comment: Don't use Dijkstra unless really needed. It is not best as it can traverse cells in opposite direction from your destination which is waste of effort.. `A*` (A star) is far more effective and still at the same implementation complexity

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski  You are mistaken about Dijsktra.  What do you mean by traversing a cell?  The performance of A* is comaparatively poor and should only be used when complete knowledge of the graph is unavailable.

Comment: *"if we visit any of the underlined node"*: If I promise I will still visit an underlined node, can I use the second weight? Or should I have visited it before using that edge?

Comment: @ravensport: By "cell" I was refering to "node". And I meant Dijkstra do not use heuristic, which A* introduced, thus is not prioritizing nodes closer to the destination, which A* does

Comment: it needs to be solved using dijkstras specificaly. and we should visit the underlined node before accessing the othe path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the graph  as graph ', and make these changes:

- In , remove the second edges, so that it only has the first edges
- In ', remove the first edges, so that it only has the second edges
- For every underlined vertex  in , add a directed edge with weight 0 from  to its copy vertex ' in '. Add also such a zero-weight edge from  to '.

Perform Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path from  to '. Map the found path to a path in the original graph, removing the (,') step from it, and the "accents".

Answer (score 0):

- Run Dijkstra on the graph using only the first weights.  Path 1
- Create a second graph
- To 2nd graph add the underlined vertices
- To 2nd graph add edges between underlined vertices using the 2nd weights
- Use Dijkstra to find cheapest path between unconnected underlined vertices in second graph, using 2nd weights.  Add edge with weight set to path weight.
- Run Dijkstra in the 2nd graph.  Path 2
- Output cheapest of Path 1 and Path 2

Comment: for the first graph should i not include vertex b and e?

Comment: The first graph is identical to the input graph, except the edges have just one weight.